# If Index Match returns a blank, choose other cell as the answer

Tags: excel-formula

If Index/Match returns a blank, how can I refer it to another cell as the answer?

I need to find a solution to ask the formula to choose 'Default Image' if the'Variant Image' is blank.

- I'm using Index Match Formula to obtain a 'Variant Image'.
- If there is no variant image I need the formula to choose the 'Default Image'

The attached image shows the formulas used to obtain 'Variant Image' and 'Default Image'.

[Example of why my Index Match formula needs an alternative when answer is blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7osE.png)

I tried adding to the formula, but it didnt work `=IFNA(),REF)`, `=IFBLANK(),REF)`.

Comment: Sounds like an IF case clearly. If index/match is blank do this, else do this

Comment: Hi Foxfire, 

Thank you for your reply. 

As i mention I attempted =IFBLANK() which did not work. 

I searched for an IF solution but could not find a suitable way to link the existing formula '=INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))' to include the IF. 
?

Comment: *If Index/Match returns a blank, how can I refer it to another cell as the answer?* IF your index formula = blank do the default image, else do the variant image. Check [IF FUNCTION](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2#:~:text=The%20IF%20function%20is%20one,if%20your%20comparison%20is%20False.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to duplicate your formula in the if statement.  Something like this should work:

`=if(INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))<>"",INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0)),VOOKUP(A23,B4:I18,8,FALSE))`

Comment: Hi Aaron, Thank you for you reply. I tried '=IF(INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))<>"",J23)' however it returns FALSE. So I am still working on solving it. Do you have a better suggestion to write this formula?

Comment: @EliseHill
In your modified formula there doesn't appear to be a False response.  You need to repeat the index formula in the true response and then have J23 as the false.  I think it should look something like this.  `=IF(INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))<>"",INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0)),J23)`

Comment: Hi Aaron, guess what! your last formula, it worked. I am really stoked. Thank you!!! SUCCESS: =IF(INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0))<>"",INDEX($I$4:$I$18,MATCH(B23&D23&F23&H23,$A$4:$A$18&$D$4:$D$18&$F$4:$F$18&$H$4:$H$18,0)),J23)